# Nginx rewrite rule inside location with php enabled

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I need to have a php application inside my default server configuration.

Also this application it was previously allocated on a apache server with rewrite rules on the `.htaccess` file  that I translated to nginx.

I'm trying to configure it all like that:

```
server {
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name _;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location /admin {
                alias /var/www/sefoanco/html;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                try_files $uri $uri/ @admin;

                rewrite ^(/admin/.*)/login/ /login/controller.php break;
                rewrite ^(/admin/.*)/observacions/ /observacions/controller.php break;
                rewrite ^(/admin/.*)/usuari/ /usuari/controller.php break;
                rewrite ^(/admin/.*)/llistat/ /llistat/controller.php break;

                location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;    

                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

            }

    location @admin {
        rewrite /admin/(.*)$ /admin/$1 last;
    }

}
```

If I access to `localhost/admin/login` I get a 403 forbidden error.

If I add the `controller.php` to the index files, it answer correctly with the php response, so I think that the php is well configured.

So I think that I forget something to config.

Comment: I think that `try_files` is messing here - try without it. The rewrite rule seems odd - I would have written it like `rewrite ^/admin/login /login/controller.php break;`

Comment: @IVOGELOV after this changes I get a `500 internal server error` and nginx error log shows: `*7 "alias" cannot be used in location "/admin" where URI was rewritten, client`

Comment: Okay, then leave the `try_files` and move the rewrite rules into `@admin` section

Comment: Now @admin section is `location @admin {rewrite /admin/(.*)$ /admin/$1 last; rewrite ^/admin/login/ /login/controller.php break; [.....] }`  and without the `try_files` but it return a 403 forbidden. On error log: `irectory index of "/var/www/sefoanco/html/login/" is forbidden`

Comment: What is the issue with adding `controller.php` to the index ?

Comment: When you try to validate on the login form it call to `login/valida/`, instead to `admin/login/valida` getting the following error as result: `"/var/www/html/login/valida/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187664/discussion-between-ivo-gelov-and-selan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was that the application are not made to work inside a path. If I see the application configuration I saw the following:

```php
$_DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

So, is easy to make it working on paths but the application doesn't work with relative paths so after make a call inside `login`, will search the auth method inside the root path.

So is needed to rewrite some parts of the application before it can work inside a path.

Anyway, I get the login page working just deleting rewrite rules and adding `controller.php` on the index param. Something like should work:

```
server {
        listen [::]:443 ;
        server_name _;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html controller.php;

        location /admin {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```